# Using jest-express, how to unit test that a middleware is being called for a given request?

Tags: unit-testing, express, jestjs

I've started using [***jest-express***](https://github.com/jameswlane/jest-express) to mock some other express-related things but am not seeing how to test the following. Here's my setup:

**./router.js**

```js
import express from "express";

const router = express.Router();
const subRouter = express.Router();
const middlewareA = (req, res) => res.send("Made it to A!");
const middlewareB = (req, res) => res.send("Made it to B!");

subRouter.use("/a", middlewareA);
subRouter.use("/b", middlewareB);
router.use("/world", subRouter);

export default router;
```

**./server.js**

```js
import express from "express";
import router from "./router";

const app = express();
app.use("/hello", router);
app.use("*", (req, res) => res.send("No router used"));
app.listen(3000);
```

I would like to write a unit test similar to the following.

```js
it(`should use "middlewareA" for a request to "/hello/world/a"`, () => {
  // ???
})
```

I'm still new to unit testing express (and Jest for that matter). I assume I would need to mock `middlewareA`, but how do I mock making a request to `"/hello/world/a"` through the express application to see if the mock `middlewareA` was called?

Or am I approaching this test wrong?